# Other challenging logarithmic integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\log(1+x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, harmonic-numbers

How can we prove that:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\log(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(5)  $$

Comment: It's curious that ${\tt \mbox{Mathematica 10.0.0.0}}$, in a MacBook Pro, yields $-\ln\left(\, 4\,\right)$ which is clearly ${\large\it\mbox{wrong !!!}}$.
$$\verb*
Clear[x];
Integrate[Log[x]^2 Log[1 - x] Log[1 + x] /x, {x, 0, 1}]*
$$

W&A [evaluates it correctly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5Bx%5D%5E2+Log%5B1+-+x%5D+Log%5B1+%2B+x%5D+%2Fx%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+1%7D%5D).

Answer (score 29):

Performing integration by parts by taking $u=\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)$, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx&=\frac{1}{3}\bigg[\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3x}{1-x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^3x}{1+x}\ dx\bigg]\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\bigg[I-J\bigg]\\
\end{align}$$
**Evaluation of $I$ :**
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\big[\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1-x)\big]}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(1+x)\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{(1+x)(1-x)}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{15}{16}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{15}{16}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to \frac{1}{2}\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\int_0^1 x^{\mu-1}(1-x)^{\nu-1}\,dx-\frac{15}{16}\lim_{\mu \to 1\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\int_0^1 x^{\mu-1}(1-x)^{\nu-1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to \frac{1}{2}\,,\, \nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\text{B}(\mu,\nu)-\frac{15}{16}\lim_{\mu \to 1\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\text{B}(\mu,\nu)\\
&=12\zeta(5)-\frac{3\pi^2}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{8}\ln{2}
\end{align}$$
**Evaluation of $J$ :**
\begin{align}
J&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\big[\ln(1-x^2)-\ln(1+x)\big]}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{(1-x)(1+x)}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x^2)}{1-x^2}\,dx-K\\
&=-\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx+\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx-K\\
&=-\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to \frac{1}{2}\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\int_0^1 x^{\mu-1}(1-x)^{\nu-1}\,dx+\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to 1\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\int_0^1 x^{\mu-1}(1-x)^{\nu-1}\,dx-K\\
&=-\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to \frac{1}{2}\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\text{B}(\mu,\nu)+\frac{1}{16}\lim_{\mu \to 1\,,\,\nu \to 0}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial\mu^3\partial\nu}\text{B}(\mu,\nu)-K\\
&=\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)-\frac{5\pi^2}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{8}\ln 2-K
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3{x}\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}H_{k}\,x^k\ln^3x\,dx\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}H_{k}\int_0^1x^k\ln^3x\,dx\\
&=-6\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{H_{k}}{(k+1)^4}\tag{2}\\
&=-6\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\left[\frac{H_{k+1}}{(k+1)^4}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^5}\right]\tag{3}\\
&=6\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\left[\frac{H_{k}}{k^4}-\frac{1}{k^5}\right]\\
&=9\eta(5)-3\zeta(5)-6\eta(2)\zeta(3)\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{87}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\zeta(3)\tag{5}
\end{align}

Putting these together, we will get the desired result.

---

**Explanation :**
$(1)$ Use generating function $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}H_{k}\,x^k=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}$
$(2)$ Use formula $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^k \ln^n x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\quad,\  n\in\mathbb{Z}_{n\ge0}$
$(3)$ Use property $\displaystyle H_{k}=H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}$
$(4)$ Use formula $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{H_{k}}{k^{2n}}=\frac{(2n+1)\eta(2n+1)}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\eta(2k)\zeta(2n+1-2k)\,,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{n\ge1}$
$(5)$ Use property of [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\displaystyle \eta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^s}=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)$

Comment: @FelixMarin I added some explanations in my answer. Thanks

Comment: +1 I think you could have avoided a lot of trouble by directly expanding the integrand as a double sum without integrating by parts.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. Thanks. Could you post your answer using that method? I want to see a different approach than mine? Thanks.

Comment: I can't post a solution now as my laptop is damaged.

By applying the aforementioned approach, one can show in a few steps that the integral is \begin{align} \small{2\sum^\infty_{j=1}\frac{(-1)^jH_j}{j^4}- 2\sum^\infty_{j=1}\frac{(-1)^j\left(\zeta(2)-H_j^{(2)}\right)}{j^3}- 2\sum^\infty_{j=1}\frac{(-1)^j\left(\zeta(3)-H_j^{(3)}\right)}{j^2}}\end{align}  These sums can be trivially evaluated. I actually prefer this to differentiating the Beta function four times and expanding everything to compute the limit.

Comment: Very nice demonstration.thank

Answer (score 4):

A generalization of the present integral is given in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (see page 6),
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^{2n}(x)\log(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2}(2n)!\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \zeta(k+1)\zeta(2n-k+2)$$

$$-(2n)!\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\right)\zeta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+3) + \frac{1}{2^{2n+3}} (2n+3-2^{2n+3})(2n)!\zeta(2n+3),$$
where in his solution the author exploits a classical series representation of $\log(1-x)\log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ denotes our integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx$

By using the generating function: $$\displaystyle\ln(1+x)\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n^2}$$
we can write

\begin{align}
I&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{n}\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln^2x\ dx-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{n^4}-\frac1{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^5}\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}-\frac74\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac18\zeta(5)
\end{align}

By plugging [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3449946) we get

> $$I=\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(5)$$

Comment: Shater +1 goog method

Comment: thank you glad you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

**Different approach:**

Let $I$ denotes our integral $\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx$

By using the identity $4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$ and setting $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ we have

$$4I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx$$

---

**The first integral:**

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx=\frac18\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n+1}\int_0^1 x^n\ln^2x\ dx\\=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac12\zeta(5)=\boxed{\zeta(5)-\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$$

---

**The second integral:**

We proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3250483)  that 
$$\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}x^{2n}$$

Then we can write 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{n}\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln^2x\ dx=16\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\\
=8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}+\frac{15}2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=\boxed{\frac{31}{4}\zeta(5)-\frac72\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$$

and the answer follows by substituting these boxed results.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)\log(1+x)}{x}dx\\
U&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)\log^3 x}{1-x}dx,V=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^3 x}{1+x}dx\\
J&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{3}\Big[\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\ln^3 x\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\Big(U-V\Big)\\
\end{align}
From [Integrating $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx$ with restricted techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3762687/integrating-int-01-frac-ln1x-ln3-x1x-dx-with-restricted-technique)

One obtains:
\begin{align*}U&=-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)\\
V&=\frac{273}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
J&=\boxed{\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(5)}
\end{align*}