# Integral $\ 4\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x)\log(1+x)}{x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How to prove that

> $$4\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x)\log(1+x)}{x}\ dx=\frac{29}4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{91}8\zeta(5)$$

Where $\chi_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}$ is the Legendre Chi function and $ \operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}$ is the Dilogarithm function.

This integral was proposed by Cornel.

Answer (score 7):

Using the relation between the Chi function and Dilogarithm we can rewrite the first integral as:
$$4\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx=2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}^2_2(x)}{x} dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{x} dx$$
You solved the first part [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3233489/515527).
$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)}{x}dx=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-3\zeta(5)$$
And the second one is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233396/closed-forms-for-the-integral-int-01-frac-rmli-nx1xdx):
$$\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x){\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}}{x}dx =-\frac54\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$$
Combinging the two results from above yields:
$$\boxed{4\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx=\frac{13}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{155}{16}\zeta(5)}$$
The second integral is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1043771/515527).
$$\boxed{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac34 \zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(5)}$$
Combining the two boxed results gives:
$$4\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x} dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(x)\ln(1+x)}{x} dx=\frac{29}4\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{91}8\zeta(5)$$

---

**Remark.**

We know from above that:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\chi_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx=\frac{13}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{155}{64}\zeta(5)$$
But integating by parts also gives us:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\int_0^1 x^{2n}\operatorname{Li}_2 (x)dx$$$$\overset{IBP}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1)}{(2n+1)^3}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}\int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln(1-x)dx$$
$$=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3) +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}$$
Which results in:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^4}=\frac34\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{155}{64}\zeta(5)$$
Alteratively one can compute that sum in a different way to find the value of the first integral.

Comment: Nice but that's the common way to go. t's a mind blowing problem because when we evaluate the two integrals together the hard sums will cancel out and we left with only easy sum. And going this way, solution will be very short very easy.

Comment: I agree with what you said. Also I didn't claim this is the best way.

Comment: Nice solution though.

Comment: @AliShather Do you have a solution too?

Comment: I have not solved it yet. I'll try today.

Comment: sorry Zacky I deleted my solution as its very similar to your solution.

Comment: @AliShather Honestly I would preffer your approach all day. It emphasized that you get rid of $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^4}$ and it's more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is pretty identical to Cornel's solution posted on his FB page.

using the fact that $\quad\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n\right),\ $ we have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n^2}\right)=\frac12\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)\right)
\end{align}

then, **the first integral**:
\begin{align}
I_1&=4\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)^2}\right)\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^2}-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)\int_0^1x^{n-1}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ dx\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{n^2}-\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}-\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_3(-1)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}\\
&\boxed{=\frac72\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}}
\end{align}
and **the second integral**:

using the following identity proved by Cornel and can be found in his book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series**. $\quad\displaystyle\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)x^{2n}$.

multiply both sides by $\displaystyle\frac{\ln^2x}{x}$ then integrate from $0$ to $1$, we get
\begin{align}
I_2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln^2x\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)\left(\frac{2}{(2n)^3}\right)\\
&=-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}+\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac18\zeta(5)\\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}+\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac18\zeta(5)\\
&\boxed{=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac74\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\frac18\zeta(5)}
\end{align}
Finally 
\begin{align}
I&=I_1+I_2\\
&=\frac72\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac18\zeta(5)-\frac{15}4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\\
&=\frac72\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac18\zeta(5)-\frac{15}4\left(3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\right)\\
&\boxed{=\frac{29}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{91}{8}\zeta(5)}
\end{align}

Comment: Oh, this way you got rid of $\sum\limits_{n\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^4}$, nice :)

Comment: Btw, small typo in the end. It's $\frac{29}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$.

Comment: thanks Zacky. its done.