# Integrating $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx$ with restricted techniques

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

> How does one calculate these four  following integrals?

$$ \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1\pm\varepsilon x)\ln(x)^3}{1\pm \varepsilon x}\,dx,\;\forall\varepsilon\in\{-1,1\}.
$$
**CONTEXT**:
Our teacher asks us to   to  calculate these four  integrals
using *only* [changes of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables), [integrations by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) and the following known result: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n(x)}{1-x} \; dx=(-1)^n n!\zeta(n+1),\quad  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^n(x)}{1+x} \; dx=(-1/2)^n (-1 + 2^n) \Gamma(1 + n) \zeta (1 + n)$$
without using complex analysis, series, [differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), double integrals or special functions.

For calculate $ 
 U =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\$
By IBP

$ U =\left[\left(\int_0^x
 \frac{\ln^3t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1
 \frac{1}{1+x}\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln^3t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
 =-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1+x)}-\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1-tx)}\right)\,dt\,dx\\
 =-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+6\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2
 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln
 x}{1+x}\,dx\right)+2\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3
 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx\right)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t
 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\$
$=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln
 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1
 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3
 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
 \overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln
 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\left[\ln\left(\frac
 {t}{1+t}\right)\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3
 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1
 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3
 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln
 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1
 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3
 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln
 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-U\\
 U =\boxed{-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln
 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)}$

Precisely, i can't see how to calculate $V=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx\\$
edit I am also interested in how to calculate the two other integrals

Comment: Are we allowed to use some generating functions? Like $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n x^n}{1+n} = \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{2x}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx}_{x\mapsto 1/x}$$

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx+\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx$$

By adding $\ \mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}\ $ to both sides, the blue integral nicely cancels out and we get

$$2\mathcal{I}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx}_{IBP}$$

$$2\mathcal{I}=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx}_{\text{Beta function:}\ 6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+6\zeta(5)}-\frac54\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx}_{\frac{45}2\zeta(5)}$$

or

$$\mathcal{I}=3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{177}{16}\zeta(5)\tag1$$

But

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$$

$$=-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx\tag2$$

Subtracting (1) and (2) yields

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=\frac{87}{16}
\zeta(5)-3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

---

The integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx$ can be calculated without using beta function:

With $\frac1{1+x}=y$ we have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\ln x}{1-x}\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}-3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}+3\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}}_{IBP}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx}_{IBP}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}-3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}}_{\large 1-x\to x}-\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large 1-x\to x}$$

$$=\frac34\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx$$
$$=\frac34(4!\zeta(5))+\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1 x^n \ln^3x\ dx$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+6\zeta(5)$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6[3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)]+6\zeta(5)$$

$$=6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+6\zeta(5)$$

---

Your integral can be related to harmonic series:

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nH_n\int_0^1 x^n \ln^3xdx$$

$$=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{(n+1)^4}=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n-1}}{n^4}$$
$$=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{n^4}+6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}$$

$$=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_{n}}{n^4}-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)$$

Comment: I followed your restrictions but I used series only for evaluating $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx$ as I saw no other ways.

Comment: Thank's for your great aswer for  $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx\\$.

Comment: I know how to compute $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx$ not using harmonic series, not using Fourier series. But for now, the method doesn't work for $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx$

Comment: FDP gives your answer. the question relates to 4 integrals

Comment: @FDP that would be interesting.

Comment: You welcome @cerise

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align*}
K&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx,C=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
K&=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt-C\right)\ln(1-x)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt-C\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^3(tx)}{(1-x)(1-tx)}\,dt\right)-\frac{C}{1-x}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-x)}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\,dt\right)-\frac{C}{1-x}\right)\,dx\\
&=6\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx\right)+\\
&\int_0^1 \left(\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{(1-t)(1-x)}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}\,dt\right)+\frac{C}{1-x}-\frac{C}{1-x}\right)\,dx\\
&=6\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\right)\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\right)+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{(1-t)(1-x)}dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}dt\right)dx\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(x)}{(1-t)(1-x)}dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}dt\right)dx\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \left(\frac{C}{1-t}-\frac{1}{t(1-t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)\right)dt\\
0&\leq A<1\\
K(A)&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^A \left(\frac{C}{1-t}-\frac{1}{t(1-t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\right)\,dt\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-C\ln(1-A)-\int_0^A \frac{1}{t(1-t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-C\ln(1-A)-\left[\ln\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)\right]_0^A+\\
&\int_0^A \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\ln(1-A)\left(\left(\int_0^A \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)-C\right)-\ln A\left(\int_0^A \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)+\\
&\int_0^A \frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}\,dt-\int_0^A \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
K&=\lim_{A\rightarrow 1}K(A)\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}\,dt-K\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-K\\
K&=\boxed{12\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}
\end{align*}
"Easier",
\begin{align*}
U&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
U&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\left(\int_0^x\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1+x)}-\frac{\ln^3(tx)}{(1+t)(1-tx)}\right)dt dx\\
&=-6\zeta(4)\ln 2+6\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx\right)+2\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 t}{1+t}dt\right)\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx\right)-\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
&=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t(1+t)}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dt\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{33}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\left[\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\frac{45}{2}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-U\\
U&=\boxed{-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)}
\end{align*}

NB:
The same method doesn't work fine for the two others integrals.

I assume that,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1+x}\,dx&=\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5),
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}\,dx=24\zeta(5)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx&=-6\zeta(4),
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx=-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(4)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx&=2\zeta(3),
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx&=-\zeta(2),
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\\
\end{align}

**Addendum**

Computation of the two other integrals.
\begin{align*}
K_1&=K,K_2=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx\\V&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx\\
K_1+U-K_2-V&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln(1-x^2)\ln^3 x}{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=x^2}=\frac{1}{8}K_1\\
V&=\frac{7}{8}K_1+U-K_2\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
C_1&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}\,dx,K_3=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\,dx-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(1+x\right)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\\&6\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(1+x\right)\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+x\right)\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2-\Big[\ln^4(1+x)\ln x\Big]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\,dx+\\
&2\Big[\ln^3(1+x)\ln^2 x\Big]_0^1-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+x)\ln x}{x}\,dx-4K_1+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2-4\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+x)\ln x}{x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\,dx-4K_2+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{2}\\
&\overset{y=\frac{1}{1+x}}=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2-4\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3 y\Big(\ln y-\ln(1-y)\Big)}{y(1-y)}dy+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^4  y}{y(1-y)}dy-\\&4K_2+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2-3\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^4 x}{x}\,dx-3\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}\,dx+4\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx+\\
&4\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\,dx-4K_2+\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)\\
&=-\frac{2}{5}\ln^5 2-3\Big(24\zeta(5)-C_1\Big)+4\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^3 x\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx+\\&4\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-4K_2+\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\frac{2}{5}\ln^5 2-3\Big(24\zeta(5)-C_1\Big)+\Big[\ln^4 x\ln(1-x)\Big]_{\frac{1}{2}}^1+\\&\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^4 x}{1-x}\,dx+4\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-4K_2+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{2}\\
&=\frac{3}{5}\ln^5 2-2\Big(24\zeta(5)-C_1\Big)+4\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-4K_2+\frac{45\zeta(5)}{2}\\
\end{align*}
On the other hand,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx&\overset{y=\frac{x}{1+x}}=C_1
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
C_1&=\frac{3}{5}\ln^5 2-2\Big(24\zeta(5)-C_1\Big)+4\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-4K_2+\frac{45}{2}\zeta(5)\\
K_2+K_3&=\frac{3}{20}\ln^5 2+\frac{1}{4}C_1+K_1-\frac{51}{8}\zeta(5)
\end{align*}
Moreover,
\begin{align*}
K_2&\overset{y=\frac{1}{1+x}}=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln y\Big(\ln y-\ln(1+y)\Big)^3}{y}\,dy\\
&=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\left(\frac{\ln^4 y}{y}-\frac{3\ln(1-y)\ln^3 y}{y}+\frac{3\ln^2(1-y)\ln^2 y}{y}-\frac{\ln^3(1-y)\ln y}{y}\right)\,dy\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\frac{1}{5}\ln^5 2-\frac{3}{4}\Big[\ln^4 y\ln(1-y)\Big]_{\frac{1}{2}}^1-\frac{3}{4}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^4 y}{1-y}\,dy+\Big[\ln^3 y\ln^2(1-y)\Big]_{\frac{1}{2}}^1+\\
&2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 y\ln(1-y)}{1-y}\,dy-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3(1-y)\ln y}{y}\,dy\\
&=\frac{9}{20}\ln^5 2-\frac{3}{4}\Big(24\zeta(5)-C1\Big)+2\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3(1-y)\ln y}{y}\,dy\\
&\overset{z=1-y}=\frac{9}{20}\ln^5 2-\frac{3}{4}\Big(24\zeta(5)-C1\Big)+2\Big(K_1-K3\Big)-K3\\
K_2+3K_3&=\frac{9}{20}\ln^5 2-18\zeta(5)+\frac{3}{4}C_1+2K_1\\
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
K_2&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}K_1-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(5)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Big(12\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\Big)-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(5)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{87}{16}\zeta(5)-3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}\\
V&=\frac{7}{8}K_1+\left(-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}K_1-\frac{9}{16}\zeta(5)\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{8}K_1+\frac{201}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
&=\frac{3}{8}\Big(12\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\Big)\Big)+\frac{201}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{273}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{45}{4}\zeta(4)\ln 2-\frac{9}{2}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}
\end{align*}